# Mongoid _destroy is not deleted embedded document using nested_form gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid, nested-forms

I am on Rails 3.1, Mongoid 2.3.3, and using the nested_form gem. In my form, I have the nested_form link_to_add and link_to_remove set up to add and remove an embedded document in my model. The link_to_add helper method works great, but the link_to_remove help method changes are not persisted in MongoDB. In the rails output, I can see the JSON parameter passed to Mongoid has the _destroy: 1 value set but the change is not saved to MongoDB.

Here is the Model:

```
class MenuItem
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name
  attr_accessible :name

  embeds_many :ingredient_infos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredient_infos, :allow_destory => true
  attr_accessible :ingredient_infos_attributes

end
```

Here is the Controller's update method:

```
  def update
    @menu_item = MenuItem.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @menu_item.update_attributes(params[:menu_item])
        format.html { redirect_to @menu_item, notice: 'Menu item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @menu_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is the parameters sent to the controller:

```
{
    "utf8"=>"✓",
     "authenticity_token"=>"5abAWfFCr7hkzYXBEss75qlq8DMQ0pW5ltGmrgHwPjQ=",
     "menu_item"=>
    {
        "name"=>"Bowl",
        "ingredient_infos_attributes"=>
        {
            "0"=>
            {
                "ingredient"=>"Rice",
                 "_destroy"=>"false",
                 "id"=>"4eb1b0b118d72f1a26000022"
            },
             "1"=>
            {
                "ingredient"=>"Chicken",
                 "_destroy"=>"1",
                 "id"=>"4eb1b0b118d72f1a26000025"
            }
        }
    },
     "commit"=>"Update Menu item",
     "id"=>"4eb1b0b118d72f1a2600001f"
}
```

In MongoDB, the Chicken document still exists; that document also shows up in the view online (the page pulls all the items in the embedded document).

I'm sure I missed something, but I haven't been able to figure out why the embedded document isn't removed.

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same issue -

RESOLVED with

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :phones, :allow_destroy => true
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, your `:allow_destory` should be `:allow_destroy`